# Finite difference discretisation of the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-differences

Here is the equation to be discretised:

$$
k\left(\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}\right) = \dot{q}
$$

Using the following discretisation scheme:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} =  \frac{T_{i+2,j} - 2T_{i+1,j} + T_{i-1,j}}{3(\Delta x)^2}  \\
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2} =  \frac{T_{i,j+2} - 2T_{i,j+1} + T_{i,j-1}}{3(\Delta y)^2} 
$$

Moreover the domain is a simple square where the left and top side have, respectively, imposed Boundary Condition $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} = 0$ & $\frac{\partial T}{\partial y} = 0$ and the right and bottom side have imposed Boundary Condition $T=T_0$.

When full discretised I get:
$$
2A \cdot T_{i+1,j} - A \cdot T_{i+2,j} - A \cdot T_{i-1,j} + 2B \cdot T_{i,j+1} - B \cdot T_{i,j+2} - B \cdot T_{i,j-1} = q_{i,j}
$$
where $A = \frac{k}{3(\Delta x)^2}$ and $B = \frac{k}{3(\Delta y)^2}$

Now I am asked to find the coefficient matrix and right hand side. The coefficient matrix is quite straight forward but my issue is the right hand side where I can't see to put in both boundary conditions...

Comment: The boundary condition $T=T_0$ is just a set of equations $T_{i,j} = T_0$ where $(i,j)$ is such that it falls on that part of the boundary. But $\dot q =0$ does not look like a boundary condition to me. Boundary conditions are supposed to involve the function you're solving for, that is $T$.

Comment: the question states that the walls are isolated thermally meaning $q_{i,j} = 0 $ which implies $ 2A * T_{i+1,j} - A * T_{i+2,j} - A * T_{i-1,j} + 2B * T_{i,j+1} - B * T_{i,j+2} - B * T_{i,j-1} = 0$

Comment: or would isolated thermally simply mean $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} = 0$ ? in that case how do you introduce the two types of boundary conditions matrix notation ?

Comment: If this is to be the heat equation then $\dot{q} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ right? Also I fixed your notation slightly: $\frac{\partial T^2}{\partial x^2} \to \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$ as the former is usually used to denote the derivative of $T^2$.

Comment: the boundary condition can be set by $2$ different ways : your $T$ unknown vector is of size $N^2$ where $N$ is the size of your discretization in both axis, the matrix $M$ of the LHS in of size $N^2 \times n^2$ and has coefficients $(i*N+j,iN^2+j) = 2$ , $(i*N+j,iN^2+j-1) = (i*N+j,iN^2+j-1) = -1$, with the equation $M \times T = C$ where $C$ is a vector of size $N^2$ with $C_{i N^2+ j} = q_{i,j}$.

Comment: then, you have two choices : remove the variables of $T$ which are known (the $4N$ values at $i=0,i=N-1$,$j = 0$,$j=N-1$) and also the one you can deduce from those and $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} = 0$ (at $i = 1$, $i=N-2$,$j = 1$, $j=N-2$). **or, my prefered way,** you could write a least square minimization equation where you minimize $||M T - C||^2+ ||K T||^2$ where $K$ is a $N^2\times 8N-4$ which directly encodes the boundary constraints : $K \times T = 0$. this is better because you didn't prove there was a solution to the constrained initial problem yet

Comment: my issue is how to incorporate that into the RHS vector, i'm having a hard time visualising you're saying ... In my opinion, you can't just remove a $T_{i,j}$ from the T vector and replace it with $T_0$ can you?

Comment: You lack information on $\dot q$, otherwise there is no hope that you can solve for $T$. (Analogy: 1 [differential] equation with two unknowns ($T, \dot Q$) can in general not be solved uniquely.)